# Transfering mysql databse from ubuntu to windows

Tags: database, transfer

I have been working on project on ubuntu lamp server. Now I need to transfer mysql databases to wamp server on windows 7. While i search in /var/lib/mysql the file type of database is different. How to make it compatible for wamp on windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqldump to create an export file and import it into the other mysql.The export is a text file, so in case the version of the new operating system is lower and you used things only available on the newer version you can edit them out. To export ...

```
 mysqldump -u {user} -p {database} >/tmp/backup.sql
```

... for every database. Use a unique name for the backup file.